# how to have live reload on Vue app with laravel in vs code on local environment?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, visual-studio-code

hi i m developing the vue app with laravel backend . I have served the app with php artisan serve at localhost:8000 and watched my asset with npm run watch but
**i want the browser to reload the vue changes** after i save . any help will be appreciated . thanks

Comment: try https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#browsersync-reloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have “hot” script available under the “scripts” section in package.json

```
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot"
```

**For more info**
https://www.webdesignvista.com/vue-hot-reload-with-laravel-mix/
I did the same with my project a couple of months ago.
Hope this article helps you.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is for laravel-mix 5, but for those now using laravel-mix 6:

Your “hot” script available under the “scripts” section in package.json should be:

```
"hot": "mix watch --hot",
```

then in your terminal run the command:

```
npm run hot
```

Now when you make a change in your IDE and save, your browser will update the change without having to reload the page

**For more info:** https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/hot-module-replacement

Comment: Make sure your 8080 port is available, otherwise it won't work and Mix won't notify you of the underlying problem. In that case you'd need to override hmrOptions using Mix's options() helper.